# Killing a Shell

Tags: node.js, express, child-process

I'm not sure this is a bug or feature, but when killing a shell (using `kill -9 <pid>`) it doesn't exit the process, as in it calls the exit event but all code continues running. Here is my code

```js
// index.js
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

const deploy = spawn(`node server`, {
  shell: true,
});

console.log(deploy.pid); // I use this to get the PID so i can use the kill command

deploy.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString());
});

deploy.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString());
});

deploy.on("exit", (code) => {
  console.log("exit");
});
```

```js
// server.js
const app = require("express")();

app.use("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log("debug");
  res.send("Hello, World");
});

app.listen(8000, () => console.log("Site Online"));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documents, using the `sh` command on Linux with the `-c` flag, 1) Fixes the problem of it not closing, 2) Allows you to run multiple commands without the `shell` option that causes the problem in the first place.

Example:

```js
const deploy = spawn("sh", ["-c", `node server && ls`], {
  stdio: ["inherit", "inherit", "inherit"],
});
```